# JDBC java compilation running

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors

I have server which communicates with database via JDBC. When I compile it

`javac -cp jdbc.jar package/Server.java`

I get nonsense errors It can't find my classes in other files. If I compile it without -cp option but run it with -cp option as:

`java -cp jdbc.jar package.Server`
I get:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: package/Server
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package.Server`

what is the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the current directory to the classpath

```
javac -cp .:jdbc.jar package/Server.java
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have managed to compile your code and are having trouble executing it.
You need to have the following in your classpath :

1. Compiled classes
2. External dependencies

Let's say your project structure looks like follows :

```
|
|-- classes
  |-- package
    |-- Server.class
|-- lib
  |-- jdbc.jar
```

Here classes contain your compiled java classes (eclipse does it neatly but you might want to look into system specific builds if you are to run them on a different remote server) and lib contains all the external dependencies (jdbc.jar in your case).

You can now run your code from the project root by adding classes and lib folders to your classpath :

```
java -cp ./classes:./lib package.Server
```

However, I strongly recommend using a standard project structure and looking into project managers like [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) for maintaining projects and building across servers.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using eclipse.
And if is that so then just copy your code paste it in some newly created file in home directory and run it.

I was facing some problem and resolved it by doing above operation. :)

Comment: Yes I wrote it in IDE but I need to run it on server via ssh so I need to compile it that way.